# Keras lstm in R: how to ensure correct input dimensions

Tags: r, keras, lstm

I am trying to run an lstm model in R. I have taken the code from here:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/
which works fine in python and tried to adapt it for R. When I run the fit process, I get the following error message:

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>   ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_6_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (400, 1)

I have read that the problem could lie with the input dimensions, but the input dimensions in R are the same as in python, ie 400x1x8 for the X data and 400 for the y data. 
I have also read that the problem could lie with the output demensions, and that specifing `return_sequences=FALSE` in the layer definition could help, but I still get the same error message.
I have included the code below, as I translated it from the MachineLearningMastery site, but without the initial data cleaning and saving step at the begining, to keep it shorter.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(keras)

source("SeriesToSupervised.R") #included at end of code
dataset <- read.table(fn, stringsAsFactors=F, comment.char="",row.names = NULL,sep=",",header=TRUE)
#label encoding windspeed 
dataset$wnd_dir_num <- 0
dataset$wnd_dir_num[dataset$wnd_dir=="NW"]<-1
dataset$wnd_dir_num[dataset$wnd_dir=="SE"]<-2
dataset$wnd_dir_num[dataset$wnd_dir=="cv"]<-3

DataToUse <- dataset[,c(2:5,10,7:9)]
rownames(DataToUse) <- dataset[,1]
DataToUse$dew <- as.numeric(DataToUse$dew)
DataToUse$snow <- as.numeric(DataToUse$snow)
DataToUse$rain <- as.numeric(DataToUse$rain)

#center and scale - used Caret here, rather than Python routines
preProcValues <- preProcess(DataToUse, method = c("center", "scale"))
scaled <- predict(preProcValues, DataToUse)

#frame as supervised learning
n_out <- 1; n_in <- 1
reframed <- SeriesToSupervised(scaled, n_in=n_in, n_out=n_out, dropnan=T)
# drop columns we don't want to predict
reframed <- reframed[,(1:(n_in*ncol(scaled)+1))]

#make training/test split
nVar <- ncol(reframed)-1
train_X <- reframed[1:400,1:nVar] #just a small sample to get things working - can expand later
test_X <- reframed[401:600,1:nVar]
train_y <- reframed[1:400,1]
test_y <- reframed[401:600,1]

# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X <- array(data=train_X,dim=c(nrow(train_X),n_in,nVar))
test_X <- array(test_X,dim=c(nrow(test_X),n_in,nVar))

# design network
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 32,
             input_shape = c(n_in,nVar)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)
model %>% compile(loss = 'mae', optimizer = 'adam')

# fit network
history <- model %>% fit(
  x=train_X, 
  y=train_y,
  epochs = 20, 
  batch_size = 72, 
  validation_data = list(test_X, test_y), 
  shuffle=FALSE,
)
```

```
SeriesToSupervised <- function(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True){
  #n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
  n_vars <- ncol(data)
  cols <- list()
  MyNames <- character(0)
  i<-n_in
  while (i > 0){
    cols[[i]] <- data.frame(shift(data, n=i))
    for (j in 1:n_vars){
      MyNames <- c(MyNames, paste0("var",j,"(t-",i,")"))
    }
    i<-i-1
  }
  for (i in 1:n_out){
    cols[[length(cols)+1]] <- data.frame(shift(data, n=(i-1)))
    for (j in 1:n_vars){
      if (i==1){
        MyNames <- c(MyNames, paste0("var",j,"(t)"))
      } else {
        MyNames <- c(MyNames, paste0("var",j,"(t+",i,")"))
      }
    }
  }
  agg <- bind_cols(cols) # put it all together
  colnames(agg) <- MyNames

  if (dropnan){ # drop rows with NaN values
    agg <- agg[complete.cases(agg),]
  }
}
```

Can anyone let me know what I can do to get this simple lstm up and running in R?

Comment: Are you sure that `y_train` dim is `(400,1)`? From your code it seems to be (400, nvars+1)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your comment. You are right, the y_train dim was wrong. I have corrected it above, but unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Do you see a different error now?

Comment: No, same error. I originally had the dim of y_train as just 400 - I added the 1 to see if that would help, but the error is still the same - it seems to me that it is more to do with an X input, rather than the y value, but I have double checked this, and my X is 3D.

Comment: The train_X dims are wrong as it seems. Could you make sure the dimensions are correct? Print the shape of train_X right before the fit method.

Comment: Yes, the dimensions of X are still 400x1x8, even just before the 'fit network' step.